# Mutating extension for Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create an extension but somehow it keeps saying:

> Ambiguous reference to member '=='.

```
class Foo: Equatable {
    var string = ""
    var number = 0

    init(string: String, number: Int) {
        self.string = string
        self.number = number
    }
}

extension Array where Iterator.Element: Foo {

    mutating func replace(object: Foo) {
        if let index = index(where: { $0.number == object.number}) {
            self[index] = object
        }
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    return lhs.number == rhs.number
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Foo doesn't conform to `Equatable`. It needs a definition for `==`

Comment: Sorry, I do have it, but I just havent shown in the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension Array where Element: Foo {

    mutating func replace(object: Element) {
        if let index = index(where: {$0.number == object.number}) {
            self[index] = object
        }
    }

}
```

To make `self[index] = object` valid, `object` needs to be an `Element` of the Array, which can be any subclass of `Foo`.

And unfortunately, Swift cannot infer the type of `Element` from the constraint to `Iterator.Element`. You may need to declare the constraint to `Element` directly.

(And to test the code above, I have removed `: Equatable` from your `Foo`, which is irrelevant when you use `index(where:)` in the extension.)

Comment: There are many combinations -- extension constraint, `object` type, using `index(where:)` or `index(of:)`... My answer is just an example and there may be another combination which fits for your purpose. Please find one by your self.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version and support multiple object replacement(add if not exist).

```
extension Foo {
    public static func == (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Foo {
    mutating func replace(object: Element) -> Bool {
        if let index = firstIndex(where: {$0 == object}) {
            self[index] = object
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    mutating func replace(objects: Array<Element>) {
        objects.forEach { (object) in
            if replace(object: object) == false {
                self.append(object)
            }
        }
    }
}
```